# How to handle different versions (Bourbon) of ruby gems on my Mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bourbon

I installed the [bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) gem on my OSX machine some weeks ago:

```
gem install bourbon
```

Now i have problems with bourbon in a web project (gulp says "mixins not found") so I wanted to uninstall and re-install the gem. So I typed:

```
$ gem uninstall bourbon
```

Surprisingly I get the following message in the terminal:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
1. bourbon-4.2.6
2. bourbon-5.0.0.beta.3
3. bourbon-5.0.0.beta.4
4. All versions
```

Hm? It seems that there are different versions of the gem installed and doing

```
bourbon install
```

in my project folder installs the latest beta (which lacks some SASS mixins I think). I thought when I install or update a gem that the older gems are deleted or overwritten. So how to handle this the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this:

```
$ gem uninstall bourbon
```

Select 4 to uninstall all the versions. Then install the gem again using the command.

```
gem install bourbon -v 4.2.6
```

Hopefully it will help.

Comment: When I uninstalled all the gem versions and installed bourbon again he automatically installed .v 4.2.6 AND the newest beta at once. I uninstalled the beta then. I don't understand why the machine installs both versions?